# Make the button the size of the blue bar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.nav-info {
  height: auto;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-left: 5%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.info a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

.appointment {
  height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: skyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav-info flexbox">
    <div class="info flexbox">
      <a href="tel:+1 (786) 859-7101">
        <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i> +1 (786) 859-7101
      </a>
      |
      <a href="email:info@gemfs.company">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> info@gemfs.company
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="appointment">
      <button class="btn">
                Make an appointment
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

I need the button to cover the entire height. I'm using flexbox, I don't know if that influences the size of the div. I have tried many things but I have no idea how to fix it. What I am trying to do is not a navbar.
On the other hand, the information of the telephone and the email are very close to each other, is there any way to remedy it using flexbox?

I want it to look like this but bottom in skyblue color. I need the button to take all the height.

[image]

Comment: you have padding

Comment: @TemaniAfif I need it to affect the size of the bar. Any way to fix it without affecting the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set fixed height for bar and apply {alight-items: stretch}.

```css
.nav-info {
        height: auto;
        background-color: darkblue;
        color: white;
        padding: 0 5%;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: stretch;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .flexbox {
        display: flex;
    }
    .separator {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 10px;
      margin-left: -2px;
    }
    .info {
        align-items: center;
    }

    .info a {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: 500;
            letter-spacing: 0.8px;
        }
     
    .appointment {
        align-items: stretch;
    }
    
    .btn {
        color: white;
        background-color: #02AC1F;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: none;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="nav-info flexbox">
        <div class="info flexbox">
            <a href="tel:+1 (786) 859-7101">
                <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i> +1 (786) 859-7101
            </a>
            <span class="separator">|</span>
            <a href="email:info@gemfs.company">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> info@gemfs.company
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="appointment flexbox">
            <button class="btn">
                Make an appointment
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</header>
```

Comment: I have added an image of how I would like it to look.

Comment: @DiesanRomero fix

Comment: Ready, now I see what the error is, but how do I make the spacing between the phone number, the email address and the bar that separates them? Can I use flex for that?

Comment: @DiesanRomero fix. I think flex is overhead

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can spread out the flex-items with the "flex" property: (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)

If you want the button to have the height of the container, one way is to set a fixed height on the container and then you can use height: 100% on the button (make sure to account for padding).